# Adding updating elements such as a level number and coin total to a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have managed to change the navigation bar to a custom stretch image and turn the back button a different colour. I'm having trouble setting a level number and coin total in the navigation bar.

I figure there has to be any easier way then messing about with progress HUD's and such - which is all I have seen mention from my research.

I'm trying to achieve a similar look to that attached below - element wise not graphically.

Thank you for any help in advance.

[image: just trying to implement a similar level and coin total]

Comment: there is a few ways... For example, you can try to subclass your UINavigationController (or UINavigationBar) and add it as Observer, then post notifications and update UI elements which is stored in your subclass (or separated class-manager) as a properties. In my current project I have UINavigationController subclass and it works perfect for me

Comment: I'm kind of a complete noob :/ and I wouldn't know how to implement that :/

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. Make the entire navigation bar into a custom view with your own elements, then update them as needed. Do this using the `titleView` property of `UINavigationItem`.
2. Use the `leftBarButtonItem`, `titleView`, and `rightBarButtonItem` with your own custom views.

I prefer the second method because it is more scalable (visually) - that is your view controller will layout correctly in landscape mode, or on an iPad, or in an oddly sized popover, etc. The left item will align to the left, the right to the right and the middle one in the middle. However, it's a bit more complicated because the left and right items need to be of type `UIBarButtonItem`. We can get around that like this:

```
// Set up the red star thing in the middle with a number 6 on it
MyRedStarView* redStarView = [MyRedStarView redStarViewWithValue:6];
self.navigationItem.titleView = redStarView;

// Set up the 'word' button on the left
MyWordButton* wordButton = [MyWordButton defaultWordButton];
UIView* buttonHolderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
buttonHolderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[buttonHolderView addSubview:wordButton];
buttonHolderView.frame = wordButton.frame;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonHolderView];

// Set up the coin indicator on the right
MyCoinView* coinView = [MyCoinView coinViewWithValue:515];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:coinView];
```

Notice how I wrapped the button (on the leftBarButtonItem) in a holder view - this is only necessary if you want to do some kind of view transitions on the button. For example if it changes in different contexts and you want to animate the transition by removing the button from the holder view and adding a different one (with a view transition). On the right bar button item I didn't do this, just to show the different approaches.

Of course I used some fake view types to demonstrate - you'd actually have your own references to these so that you can set the property values and update the display of the numbers.

Comment: How would I attach the coin image next to the coin label?

Comment: Make a view and `addSubview:` for the `UIImageView` and `UILabel` - this is your `coinView`. It doesn't have to be a custom type (such as `MyCoinView`) - it can be a plain old `UIView`, but you will need references to the label for setting the text. It is sometimes useful to make custom view types that contain layout rules and a few sub-views and perhaps some properties to easily set values - like an integer `numCoins` property for example, then the display handling happens in your custom view class. This is cleaner, but not necessary to achieve your goal, I'd say it's a more advanced way.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code assuming you already have the navigationView in place

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 // Custom Navigation Bar
    // -----------------------------------
    UIView *navigationCustomTitle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 20.0)];
    navigationCustomTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIImageView *icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]];
    UILabel *titleCustomLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0, 0.0, 260.0, 20.0)];
    titleCustomLabel.text = @"A nice title";
    titleCustomLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    titleCustomLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleCustomLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:(16.0)];

    [navigationCustomTitle addSubview:titleCustomLabel];
    [navigationCustomTitle addSubview:icon];


    self.navigationItem.titleView = navigationCustomTitle;

}
```